# colown count does not match value count at row 1

Tags: java

i am a beginner in java Desktop application, and i was trying to insert some data into my table and i get the following reply "colown count does not match value count at row 1" here is my query

```
 String sql = "insert into cataloguetb(title_statement,aurthurs_name,edition_statement,book_title,publisher_name"
                   + "place_of_publication,year_of_publication,isbn_no,index_no,pagenRomannuem,pagneArabi,illuss,size_of_book"
                   + "otherAurthurs,addEntries,length_in_cm,accessionNO,call_No1,call_No2,call_No,call_No4)values ('"+(titleStatement)+"','"+(aurthursName)+"'"
                   + "'"+(editionStatement)+"','"+(bookTitle)+"','"+(publisherName)+"','"+(placeOfPublication)+"','"+(yearOfPublication)+"'"
                   + "'"+(isbnNo)+"','"+(indexNo)+"','"+(pageRoman)+"','"+(pageArabic)+"','"+(illustration)+"','"+(size)+"','"+(otherAuthurs)+"'"
                   + "'"+(addedEntries)+"','"+(lengthOfBook)+"','"+(accessionNo)+"','"+(calNo1)+"','"+(calNo2)+"','"+(calNo3)+"','"+(calNo4)+"')";
```

i have tried so many solutions even from stacflowoverflow there seem to no solution thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

This is because number of columns that you want to enter and datas(values for columns) you are entering are not same

the output of your code will be something like this

```
insert into cataloguetb(title_statement,aurthurs_name,edition_statement,book_title,publisher_nameplace_of_publication,year_of_publication,isbn_no,index_no,pagenRomannuem,pagneArabi,illuss,size_of_bookotherAurthurs,addEntries,length_in_cm,accessionNO,call_No1,call_No2,call_No,call_No4)values (.......)
```

That means you trying to insert in 19 columns but giving 21 values.So the error.

Well it is not the proper way of insertion.
Better would be to use PreparedStatement like this way

```
PreparedStatement pt=con.prepareStatement("insert into table (x,y) values(?,?");
pt.setString(1,value_for_x);
pt.setString(2,value_for_y);
pt.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: thanks for commenting on my insert query but what are the values of x,y

Comment: @user2776664 x and y are the column names,I gave an example how to do using preparedStatement

Answer (score 0):

You need trailing commas on the fields at the end of the rows. Try this:

```
String sql = "insert into cataloguetb(title_statement,aurthurs_name,edition_statement,book_title,publisher_name,"
                   + "place_of_publication,year_of_publication,isbn_no,index_no,pagenRomannuem,pagneArabi,illuss,size_of_book,"
                   + "otherAurthurs,addEntries,length_in_cm,accessionNO,call_No1,call_No2,call_No,call_No4) values ('"+(titleStatement)+ "','"+(aurthursName)+"',"
                   + "'"+(editionStatement)+"','"+(bookTitle)+"','"+(publisherName)+"','"+(placeOfPublication)+"','"+(yearOfPublication)+"',"
                   + "'"+(isbnNo)+"','"+(indexNo)+"','"+(pageRoman)+"','"+(pageArabic)+"','"+(illustration)+"','"+(size)+"','"+(otherAuthurs)+"',"
                   + "'"+(addedEntries)+"','"+(lengthOfBook)+"','"+(accessionNo)+"','"+(calNo1)+"','"+(calNo2)+"','"+(calNo3)+"','"+(calNo4)+"')";
```

Comment: thanks it works i am very grateful Monkjack you have delivered me from a three days of strugle